# Primes generating perl

Tags: perl, primes

I'm trying to generate random prime number

```
print Math::Prime::Util->random_strong_prime(128);
```

But, when I call one of the methods (i tried various) of [Math::Prime::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Prime::Util), I get:

`Parameter 'Math::Prime::Util' must be a positive integer at /home/ivan/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Math/Prime/Util.pm line 400.`

I can't understend what's wrong, 128 is positive and integer.
Script runs under Starman server(psgi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use [the method invocation syntax](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlobj#Method-Invocation), i.e.,

> ```
> Math::Prime::Util->random_strong_prime(128);
> ```

the first argument to `random_strong_prime` becomes the string `"Math::Prime::Util"` which is not a positive integer. With method invocation syntax, `128` becomes the ***second*** parameter.

The syntax you are using is appropriate for invoking a class method.

Instead, you want to use function invocation syntax:

```
print Math::Prime::Util::random_strong_prime(128);
```

You can verify this using the following simple program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

package Hello;

sub f { print "@_\n" }

package main;

Hello->f('world');
Hello::f('world');
```

```
$ ./gg.pl
Hello world
world
```